# How to create custom Formula Field on FluentNHibernate Autommaping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose the next entity

```
public class Result
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Sku Sku { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Payer Payer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual double StkPrev { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual double StkCurrent { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual double Buy { get; set; }
    public virtual double SellOut {get { return StkPrev + Buy - StkCurrent; }}
 ... }
```

I need to specifically map the property "SellOut" in the database.

How should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public virtual double SellOut { get; private set; }
```

and

```
Map(x => x.SellOut).Formula("Some Sql here");
```